# Javascript draggable event handlers on class - setting multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, event-handling, draggable

In most cases, I've been setting an event class handler that will apply to subsequently created elements of that class as follows:

`$('#container').on('click', '.myClass', function (e) {...`

However, I don't know how to do this with `draggable`. The following doesn't affect subsequently created objects:

`$('.myClass').draggable(...`

As a consequence, I've been repeatedly making the class draggable (with the line above) after each new draggable object is created.

What I want to know is whether this is creating multiple event handlers on the class, or am I just reestablishing the same handler?  Is there some equivalent to `.off()` that I should be using?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `destroy` method to remove draggable and then reinitialize it like

```
$('.myClass').draggable('destroy').draggable(...
```

Read more here http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#method-destroy

Comment: @Nick, No Problem, You are most welcome. Glad to be able to help. :)